# exclude root user from getting /etc/profile.d

Tags: debian, centos

I have a custom /etc/profile.d that gets copied to each client when they login.  I need for the root login to not get this profile copied over.  What is the best way to accomplish this?
We have this setup for both Debian and CentOS systems.

Comment: Why aren't you using `/etc/skel` and user-specific files for this? `/etc/profile.d` is a system-wide file.

Comment: Also, how are you doing the copy? You could simply add a condition and not copy it if the user name is `root` or, better, if the UID is `0`.

Comment: Isn't /etc/profile.d/ a directory? I second terdon's comment -- show what you're doing, and we can hopefully show you how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the /etc/profile script by appending the if uid not != 0

```
for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh /etc/profile.d/sh.local ; do
    if [[ -r "$i" ]] && [[ $UID -ne 0 ]]; then
        if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then 
            . "$i"
        else
            . "$i" >/dev/null
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: I don't like this answer, because it looks like default Red Hat has a lof of things relevant for root and that there should be a better solution, like different folders. Anybody has done something more clever?